# Redirect Github homepage to custom homepage

Tags: github, redirect, github-pages, http-redirect, custom-domain

I used to host my webpage on `username.github.io`.

I have now set up a new webpage on `username.com`, and has no relation to `username.github.io`.

However, I want to redirect `username.github.io` to `username.com`.
As of now, if somebody enters `username.github.io`, it takes you to the 404 not found page.

Is there anyway I can reroute it to `username.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a redirect, the normal process is for your current GitHub pages to [use a custom domain](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)

You find a [better illustration of that process here](https://medium.com/@hossainkhan/using-custom-domain-for-github-pages-86b303d3918a#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20GitHub%20Pages,CNAME%20in%20the%20same%20repository.)

> - Go to your GitHub Pages site’s repository settings.
>   Under “Custom domain”, add or remove your custom domain and click “Save”.
> - Setting “custom domain” creates a file named CNAME in the same repository.
>   Don’t delete it.

The [OP sidv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4091351/sidv) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662551/redirect-github-homepage-to-custom-homepage/63665897?noredirect=1#comment112592526_63665897):

> After setting up my website (deployed elsewhere) and the DNS servers, I was unable to open the webpage on Safari and Firefox (only on Chrome).
>
> Finding the load balancing IP and configuring it as an A record ended up redirecting the webpage appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! This was really helpful. The resources here helped solve **another** issue I was facing. For anyone who might face a similar predicament in the future -- after setting up my website (deployed elsewhere) and the DNS servers, I was unable to open the webpage on Safari and Firefox (only on Chrome). Finding the load balancing IP and configuring it as an A record (found in @VonC's link) ended up redirecting the webpage appropriately.

Comment: @SidV Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.